# Sending database information from one webapp to another

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets

I have two GWT webapps, that may or may not be deployed on the same tomcat server. One webapp(lets say WebApp1), will retrieve a bunch of data from various sources, and then store the data in an object on a database. Now, WebApp1 must give WebApp2 the database key for this object (NoSQL). How would I go about sending this database key to WebApp2?

Comment: Does this have to be synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: There is no system requirement.

Comment: If WebApp1 knows the host for WebApp2, just make an endpoint (WS or otherwise) on WebApp2 that accepts a key.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: Your webapp has an http interface. For example, you could have `www.yourhost.com/yourWebApp/postKey?key=1234`

Comment: Ok, so are you thinking that I should have WebApp2 sending GET requests on a specified cosntant interval, and having WebApp1 post the database key when it has it? Is there some sort of HTTP listener, that would execute when a POST is received from WebApp1?

Comment: In your web.xml, you can map a Servlet class to the "/postKey" pattern. Since the related data is being stored in a database, another approach is to have the receiving app poll for new data in the database.